# How to Translate lightning components(custom labels) based on languages

Tags: salesforce, lightning

I want to add multi language functionality on my lightning component.
I am not able to find anything useful.
As now i am able to translate only currency and timepicker only.But i want to translate all the custom label (like in VF pages)..

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I'm new to lightning although I have extensive experience with Apex and so far the only way I can see this happening is to do a metadata call from Apex to generate the list of custom labels and its equivalent language and consume that that on the lightning component controller/helper via the init event. I can't find anything in the lightning developer guide on how to dynamically do this like in visualforce page.

Hope someone can confirm too.